# SSD does not work in external enclosure

Tags: ssd

I have a SATA SSD with an USB3 external enclosure. So I want to use as an external drive. The enclosure works with HDD and the SSD works in a PC but the SSD does not work in the external enclosure. I tested with 3 different PC (Windows 10 and 8) but nothing happen, does not show anywhere.

Comment: Are you plugging it in USB 2 or USB 3 port? Are there any partitions on the SSD? Does 'Anywhere' include Administrative Tools -> Disk Management console? Are both HDD as well as SSD 2.5" form factor?

Comment: @patkim - Why should the form factor matter, as long as the physical interfaces (i.e., SATA connectors, or IDE pinset and power connector for older drives) are compatible?

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin  OP has not specified details of the enclosure. If OP is putting in 2.5 in 3.5 though in principle the SATA connections should work and also the fact that 2.5 does not use +12V, the drive may not be securely placed inside the case, just a small possibility. OP may like to elaborate on the details of the enclosure additionally by editing the question.

Comment: @patkim - 12V vs 5V or other voltage discrepancies would indeed be an issue, but that's not "form factor" as I understand the term. The physical issue of a small drive rattling around unsecured in a large case _is_ something to consider, but is unlikely to be a major issue in merely getting the device to talk to the computer.

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning the disk while its in the enclosure?

Comment: The enclosure is outdated, replace it.

Comment: @patkim In order: both / no, because I cant access / no / yes

Comment: @patkim  SSD and enclosure are 2.5", SATA

Comment: @davidgo No, I cant, nothing "see" the disk in the enclosure.

Comment: @Moab Maybe, but what should I pay attention when I replace to a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue with a Sabrent 2.5" to USB 3.0 enclosure. This is I've purchased several enclosures by various manufacturers and never had a problem. This is the first enclosure that has refused to initialize SSDs. I can boot up mechanical HDDs no problem. I can take this SSD and switch it into a known working enclosure and it will work as well.

I believe it has to do with the fact that this particular enclosure differs from the others in the way that it has a USB 3.0 A cable connector on the disk interface side.

Taking a second look at the advertisement it actually says "optimized for SSD" but i tried 2 different SSDs from diff manufacturers on it before trying my mechanical HDD just as a sanity check to see if it even worked or if i needed to return it.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OJ3UJ2S?ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OJ3UJ2S)

Anyways, lesson learned I guess... I'll just have to be doubly careful next time.

The other enclosures all have USB "SuperSpeed" 3.0 micro b on the disk interface side which is the only difference I can tell. Perhaps this interface is dated? Its disappointing bc I cant use it with the disk I intended to purchase it for. But i'll keep it around for use on a disk in the future.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1081414)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
However, the issue seems to be related to the SATA M.2 SSD capacity.
I have two different enclosures. Both enclosures work with the 1 TB capacity SSD and not with the 2 TB capacity SSD.
The 2 TB capacity SATA SSD cannot be formatted with fast format.
However, normal formatting works.
This does not help in case of disk cloning software.
Disk cloning software deletes all partition on the destination disk.
As a rule, the clone software tries to create and (only fast) format destination partitions, which will fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).